# When writing a comment header for documentation, how do I specify that this function returns another function?

Tags: php, documentation, styles, comments

As an example:

```
/**
 * foo function
 * @param Fooby $fooby
 * @return ????
 **/
 public function foo(Fooby $fooby) {

     if ($fooby == self::BAR) {

         return $this->bar();

     }

     return 'foobar';         
 }
```

Where the ???? is, if the condition results in only a string, I could write `@return string`, however how do I document the return of the result of the `bar()` method?.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In such condition, you need to check what are the possibilities of `$this->bar()` , there can be two cases:

1. Its sure that `$this->bar()` will always be a string, in that case use:

`@return string`

2. Its not sure whats gonna be the type of `$this->bar()` , in that case use:

`@return mixed`